# Change HTML Attribute value

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to change the value of a hidden type in form after running a JS function. The value of distance seems to be correct. But the assignment doesn't seem to be working when I am accessing the $_POST['distance'] in next page it still returns 1000 without changing the value. Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcRoute() {
    var start = "1255 E University Dr, Tempe, AZ 85281";
      var end = "KPMG, 60 E Rio Salado Pkwy, Tempe, AZ 85281";
      var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            window.distance = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
            alert(window.distance);             
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
      });
   document().getElementById('distance').value = window.distance;
}
</script>
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="calcRoute()">calc</button>
<form method="post" action = "getdist.php">
<input type = "hidden" name="distance" id="distance" value="1000">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you updating `window.distance`, rather than `document.getElementById('distance')`? I'm not entirely sure that this solves your problem, but I'd suggest trying it.

Comment: window.distance is just to make the distance a global variable. I am finding the window.distance value first and I want to assign that value to html attribute 'distance'.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `document.getElementById('distance').value = window.distance;` instead :)

Also, you should possible put that statement inside the function where you assign window.distance, because that document.getElementById() thing will be called when the interpreter gets to that line of calcRoute where as the line where you actually assign a value to window.distance is a callback function passed to directionsService.route, so there's no way to know that window.distance will actually have a value when you try to get it, because the callback function can be called whenever directionsService.route decides to.

Remember that javascript is asynchronous.

Comment: Couldn't get you... you mean to say don't use ".value" in there ??

Comment: no no, just change `document()` to `document`. The rest of the line is correct.

Comment: Awesome... that did the trick!! I can't believe I missed that... thank you chris.

Comment: Oh, except for that you should probably move that line into where you say window.distance = ....